# Posting a verbal analogy

Tags: discussion

I need help with solving verbal analogies, but don't know which forum would be the right one.  ELU?  ELL?  Puzzling?  Also, would I need to cite the source?  And could I do several in one post?

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand why B is necessarily the correct answer here. Depending on how I interpret the relationship between *dimple* and *pimple*, E, for instance, could be better. So, I think that regardless of the forum, the question itself would need more clarification.

Comment: Yes, I had the same reaction to the "correct" answer, @JasonBassford.   On the very first practice page, they explain each answer, but after that, they only give the right answer, period.

Comment: **Am I the only one, or can others also not get the image links such as the one in this question to work??** I dont know if my computer doesnt like linking to the site (i.stack.imgur.com???) where the images are or what.

Comment: I think that analogy test questions, at bottom, aren't exercises in language or usage. Perhaps the most accurate category name for them is "tendentious reasoning." Here the test question preparer has decided that because dimples are depressions and pimples are protuberances—that is, because in one instance the skin sinks down and in the other it rises up—the suitable comparison is B (down is to up). But if you focused not on the behavior of the skin, but on a possible visceral reaction to dimples and pimples, E would be a better choice. I think the entire test category is fatally subjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a question like this could find a home at [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

As for advice to help the question fare well, I'd say:

- The community prefers the question and answers be typed out, not merely posted as a screen shot.
- Yes, you should cite the source. It helps to know where you got the question from.
- No, you shouldn't do several in one post. That just makes it harder to fully answer your question with a single answer.
- Insomuch as you can, you should try to tell us what you can about which answers you've eliminated, or what hunches you may have. If you're utterly stumped, that's fine, but at least say as much, so the entire community isn't wondering where you stand on the matter.
- Adding your research will also help. At the very least, you could tell us what you found when you looked up some of the words in the question in few dictionaries.

In this case, it seems the two words are being compared by shape. Dimples are concave, pimples are convex. The fact that they rhyme is a red herring. The fact that they also can both be seen on the face might also be misleading; I think the analogy makes more sense if you think of dimples on a golf ball, and remember that [pimple](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pimple) can mean (among other things) "a little elevation or protuberance of any kind."

Comment: J.R., so I take it (and I agree) that such questions are not on topic on ELU (or rather they'd have to be worded quite beyond recognition from the original). But that doesn't mean the ELL people will like it either.

Comment: OP should also keep in mind that multiple choice tests rarely have subtle answers that are correct.  Stomp down any original thinking when you are taking a multiple choice test.

Comment: @Mitch - It may be hard to please all of the people all of the time, but, if the OP followed the guidance I've provided in my answer, I'm pretty confident the resulting question would be fine on ELL.